# How to update multiple SQL records, with merge with multiple options, based on an XML document?

Tags: sql, sql-server, xml, database

I'm a newbie to SQL (about a week), and I have a problem I can't figure out.

I have a bunch of xml files that have a structure somewhat like this:

```
<foods>
     <type>
       <food_id>123456789</food_id>
       <food_type>bacon</food_type>
       <food_information>
           <stuff>blah</stuff>
       </food_information>
       <more_food_info>
           <more_stuff>blah</more_stuff>
       </more_food_info>
     </type>
     <type>
       <food_id>123456780</food_id>
       <food_type>eggs</food>
       <food_information>
           <stuff>blahblah</stuff>
       </food_information>
       <more_food_info>
           <more_stuff>blahblahblah</more_stuff>
       </more_food_info>
     </type>
</foods>
```

I am doing Bulk inserts in T-SQL. Now, this database contains tens of millions of records of food. Almost NOTHING is unique, except one unique value, "food_id." It is always unique. However, newer XML files contain updates for the old records, and I need to be able to use ONLY those new records (based on food_id). So, I need to merge/update/delete the entire record.

**food_information** is a table containing a bunch of stuff.

**more_food_info** is also another table containing a bunch of stuff.

Here's part of my insertion code:

```
DECLARE @xml_data xml
DECLARE @xdoc INT

SET @xml_data = (SELECT CONVERT(xml, BulkColumn, 2) FROM OPENROWSET(Bulk 'foods.xml', SINGLE_CLOB) [rowresults])

EXEC sp_xml_preparedocument @xdoc, OUTPUT, @xml_data

INSERT INTO [type]
    SELECT * FROM OPENXML(@xdoc, '/foods/type', 2)
    WITH
    (
        [food_id] VARCHAR(8) 'food_id',
        [food_type] VARCHAR(255) 'food_type',
    )

INSERT INTO [food_information]
    SELECT 
        [type].[Type_ID], 
        xml.[stuff] FROM [type]
    INNER JOIN OPENXML(@xdoc, '/foods/type/food_information', 2)
    WITH 
    ( 
        [food_id] VARCHAR(8) '../food_id', 
        [stuff] VARCHAR(255) 'stuff'
    )
    AS XML ON xml.[food_id] = [type].[food_id]
    -- Repeat the same style for every other table... (not the same as the [type] table)

EXEC sp_xml_removedocument
```

This works, but I need to be able to match everything from these foreign keys in the other tables, to the primary key in the main table ([type]), and, of course, to the serial number, to update all records based on it. I don't know how to do this for multiple records.

I need all tables joined in a MERGE update, but I only know how to merge the FIRST table since I can't seem to insert other conditions from other tables. **Or** I need a way to find all records relating to that **food_id** and delete the lowest **Type_ID** number (primary key) for each record and match that to the corresponding foreign key to delete the other records in the other tables.

The problem is that food_id when reading bulk xml returns a giant list of ids. I only want the one we're currently on, so I can't compare it. And "IN (select statement)" is not what I'm looking for: it has to be one at a time.

**TLDR**: How do I do this? psuedo-code:

```
Read XML document.
If exists (SELECT [food_id] from [type] WHERE [food_id] = current_xml_food_id)
    THEN
    -- Update/MERGE stuff
    -- Include all the other tables that need updating: 
    -- ... food_information, more_food_info, etc.
    -- ...and make sure the foreign key relationship stays
    -- ...intact. We need to match Type_ID (main table 
    -- ...PrimaryKey) to TableName_ID (ForeignKey)
    ELSE
    -- Insert stuff
End read
```

**EDIT**: I need one of these solutions, but I don't know how to any do them:

- If record exists, use merge to update records.
- If record exists, delete it (and all accompanying records with the same foreignkey_id) and insert the new record
- If more than one copy of [food_id]'s value exists, delete the LOWEST number based on it's primary key. The highest primary key number will always be the newest one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I thought this question was really badly put together, so I made another one with a better explanation. This has been solved by Blam. Thanks, Blam!

[How do I delete duplicate records, or merge them with foreign-key restraints intact?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26166986/how-do-i-delete-duplicate-records-or-merge-them-with-foreign-key-restraints-int)