# How do I delete duplicate records, or merge them with foreign-key restraints intact?

Tags: sql, xml, t-sql

I have a database generated from an XML document with duplicate records. I know how to delete one record from the main table, but not those with foreign-key restraints.

I have a large amount of XML documents, and they are inserted without caring about duplicates or not. One solution to removing duplicates is to just delete the lowest Primary_Key values (and all related foreign key records) and keep the highest. I don't know how to do that, though.

The database looks like this:

**Table 1: [type]**

```
+-------------+---------+-----------+
| Primary_Key | Food_ID | Food_Type |
+-------------+---------+-----------+
|   70001     |  12345  |  fruit    |
|   70002     |  12345  |  fruit    |
|   70003     |  12345  |  meat     |
+----^--------+---------+-----------+
     |
     |-----------------|
                       |    
                       | Linked to primary key in the first table
+-------------+--------v--------+-------------+-------------+------------+
| Primary_Key |  Information_ID |   Food_Name | Information |  Comments  | 
+-------------+-----------------+-------------+-------------+------------+
|   0001      |     70001       |   banana    |  buy @ toms | delicious! |
|   0002      |     70002       |   banana    |  buy @ mats | so-so      |
|   0003      |     70003       | decade meat |  buy @ sals | disgusting |
+-------------+-----------------+-------------+-------------+------------+
```

^ **Table 2: [food_information]**

There are several other linked tables as well, which all have a foreign key value of the matched primary key value in the main table ([type]).

My question based on which solution might be best:

1. How do I delete all of those records, except 70003 (the highest one)? We can't know if it's duplicate record unless **[Food_ID]** shows up more than once. If it shows up more than once, we need to delete records from ALL tables (there are 10) based on the Primary_Key and Foreign_Key relationship.
2. How do I update/merge these SQL records on insertion to avoid having to delete multiples again?

I'd prefer #1, as it prevents me from having to rebuild the database, and it makes inserting much easier.

Thanks!

Comment: what table are you deleting from..?

Comment: [type], [food_information], [more_information], [table4], [table5], [table6], [table7], [table8], [table9], [table10]. All tables except [type] have the same ForeignKey value; it's based on [type]'s PrimaryKey. However, food_id is the only unique value in the database (even though there are duplicate records).

Comment: Not clear. Main table doe not even have a [type].  According to the picture the link is to Primary_Key.

Comment: As far as not have multiples again just put a unique constraint on [FoodID]

Comment: Sorry, let me try to rephrase that. [type] is linked to [food_information] through [type]'s Primary_Key, and [food_information]'s Information_ID. If I see an example for deleting, I can apply that example to the rest of the tables.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Even if a [foodID] is not duplicated you will get a max(Primary_Key)
And it will not be deleted
The where condition is NOT in

```
delete tableX 
 where tableX.informationID not in ( select max(Primary_Key) 
                                       from [type] 
                                   group by [foodID] )


then just do [type] last


delete [type] 
 where [type].[Primary_Key] not in ( select max(Primary_Key) 
                                       from [type] 
                                      group by [foodID] )
```

then just create as unique constraint on [foodID]

Comment: This works perfectly for the other tables! We're almost there! However, I don't know how to delete the records for the main table, [type], using this method. It runs perfectly one time, but when I run it again, it deletes all records in the database.

Comment: It should not.  Please post your final delete.  You did not slip a where count(*) > 1 in there did you?

Comment: DELETE [Table1]
WHERE [Table1].[ForeignKey_ID] NOT IN (SELECT MAX([PrimaryKey_ID]) FROM [type] GROUP BY [Food_ID] HAVING COUNT(*) > 1)

DELETE [Table2]
WHERE [Table2].[ForeignKey_ID] NOT IN (SELECT MAX([PrimaryKey_ID]) FROM [type] GROUP BY [Food_ID] HAVING COUNT(*) > 1)

DELETE [Table3]
WHERE [Table3].[ForeignKey_ID] NOT IN (SELECT MAX([PrimaryKey_ID]) FROM [type] GROUP BY [Food_ID] HAVING COUNT(*) > 1)

DELETE [type]
WHERE [Food_ID] NOT IN (SELECT MAX([PrimaryKey_ID]) FROM [type] GROUP BY [Food_ID] HAVING COUNT(*) > 1)

Comment: Why did you put in a HAVING COUNT() > 1?  That is NOT in my answer.  I even explain you will even if [foodID] is not duplicated you will get a max(Primary_Key).  What you by adding that having is also delete any foodID that had no duplicates.

Comment: I am not quite sure.. I thought I saw that in your original answer. I deleted that ("HAVING COUNT() > 1"), and I'm still having the same effect; everything is deleted.

Comment: PERFECT! I made a typo on the last part. THIS WORKS PERFECTLY! I love you. I've been wrestling with this problem for a week (I am very new to SQL). Thanks so much!

Answer (score 0):

something like...

assumed:

```
create table food (
  primary_key int,
  food_id int,
  food_type varchar(20)
  );

insert into food values (70001,12345,'fruit'); 
insert into food values (70002,12345,'fruit'); 
insert into food values (70003,12345,'meat'); 
insert into food values (70004,11111,'taco'); 

create table info (
  primary_key int,
  info_id int,
  food_name varchar(20)
  );

insert into info values (1,70001,'banana'); 
insert into info values (2,70002,'banana'); 
insert into info values (3,70003,'decade meat'); 
insert into info values (4,70004,'taco taco');
```

and then...

```
-- yields:   12345   70003 

select  food_id, max(info_id) as max_info_id
from    food 
        join info on food.primary_key=info.info_id
where   food_id in ( 
            select food_id
            from   food 
                   join info on food.primary_key=info.info_id
            group  by food_id
            having count(*)>1);
```

then... something like... this to get the ones to delete.  there might be a better way to write this... i'm thinking about it.

```
select  *
from    food 
        join info on food.primary_key=info.info_id 
        join ( select  food_id, max(info_id) as max_info_id
               from    food 
                       join info on food.primary_key=info.info_id
               where   food_id in ( 
                           select food_id
                           from   food 
                                  join info on food.primary_key=info.info_id
                           group  by food_id
                           having count(*)>1) 
               ) as dont_delete
            on food.food_id=dont_delete.food_id and 
               info.info_id<max_info_id
```

gives you:

```
PRIMARY_KEY FOOD_ID FOOD_TYPE   INFO_ID FOOD_NAME   MAX_INFO_ID
70001       12345   fruit       70001   banana      70003
70002       12345   fruit       70002   banana      70003
```

so you could do.... just `delete from food where primary_key in (select food.primary_key from that_big_query_up_there)` and `delete from info where info_id in (select food.primary_key from that_big_query_up_there)`

for future issues, maybe consider a unique constraint on `food`... `unique(primary_key,food_id)` or something but if it's one-to-one, why don't you just store them together...?

Comment: See my answer.  You are making this way harder than it need to be.

Comment: Thanks for the effort, gloomy, but that's way too much work. Blam's answer worked perfectly, and it's blazingly fast.